# For adjectives which one applies? ように or ような

Tags: grammar

Is ように solely for verbs while のような for nouns? What about adjectives?

Answer (score 5):

I think it is best if you just treat 様【よう】 as a normal noun. With other nouns, you should be using のよう because that is how nouns modify each other. With na-adjs, you should be using なよう because that is how they modify nouns. And so on. So:

> 学生のように 
> Like a student

> お好きな様に 
> as you like

> 優しい様に 
> In a nice way

For whether you should be using ような or ように, the same applies. な used by な-adj to describe a noun while に is used to make it an adverb. For example, きれいに makes it an adverb while きれいな is an adjective. In the same way, ような makes it an adj while ように makes it an adverb. This means choosing between the two depends on what よう is modifying.

> 学生のように勉強する。
> Study like a student.

> 学生のような制服。
> A uniform like a student's.

Adverbs, much like in English, can also modify adjectives, so you would use ように

> 彼のように優しい 
> Nice like him

Comment: I am still confused on how to differentiate both ように and ような‘s meaning. As per the example given above, 学生のように勉強する。
(Study like a student.) and 学生のような制服。
(A uniform like a student's.); both ように and ような meant “similar to, looks like”. Pls correct if me i am wrong. I-Adjective will use ように is it?

Comment: @littlechicken Maybe I didn't make this clear, but choosing between ような and ように depends one *what it is modifying*. In ように勉強する, ように modifies a *verb* (勉強する), which means ように must be used because it is an *adverb*. ような制服 modifies a *noun* (制服), which means you need to choose ような because *adjectives are used to modify nouns*.

Comment: The only difference between ように and ような is their part of speech. They mean the same thing because they are both just the word よう with particles attached to them.

Comment: Therefore, ように is used if the predicate is a verb. While ような is modifying the noun that follows it. Am I right to say so?

Comment: @littlechicken yes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of understanding this as well. As per my understanding adverb are words like honto  ni,  zettai, totemo, hayaku eg. are used to add more description to a verb or noun.

1. Chichi no you na otona ni naritai desu.
   (When I grow up I want to be someone like my father)
2. Ningyo no you na kao desu.
   (Face which is similar to a doll's)

How about this example :

Sentaku mondai no you ni tesuto ga ii desu Vs sentaku  mondai  no you na tesuto ga ii desu.

Comment: maybe that's a typo, but adverbs cannot modify nouns, only verbs and sometimes adjectives.